# Maple - how to print assign of an array into xml file?

Tags: xml, file, printing, maple

So I perform some operation like

```
out := Minimize(function(param1, paramN));
```

from this I getsomething like array of pairs Name=Value printed out

and than I do:

```
     assign(out[2]);
```

I want to print out[2] into xml in a way like

```
<param1>
value
</param1>
...
<paramN>
value
<ParamN>
```

How to do such thing (how to print anarray of pairs Name=Value into XML in desired form- not in mathML?)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using XMLTools package?

Documentation: [Overview of the XMLTools Package](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=XMLTools)

You can also check [these examples](http://www.maplesoft.com/applications/view.aspx?SID=4190&view=html) (in an earlier version, but I suppose the logic is there)

EDIT:

quick example (I haven't used XMLTools before, but I think it's not far):

```
(out[1] contains names and out[2] values)

> with( XMLTools );
> doc := XMLElement("params", [], seq(XMLElement(out[1][i], [], out[2][i])))
> print(doc)

<params>
  <param1>value1</param1>
  ...
  <paramN>valueN</paramN> 
</params>
```

Comment: Could you provide any example for my case - how to print array of pairs name=walue into xml?

Comment: as for me maple always gives something like `Error, invalid input: parse expects its 1st argument, st, to be of type string, but received pn2 = -.433220950080607847` even after I try stuff like `convert(parse(out[2][2]))`